# Trying to dockerize a github repository for the first time -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, docker, github, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize [this repository](https://github.com/jappareti/better-southwest-search) so that I can run it on my local server.

I've created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -pv $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD . $APP_HOME

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
EXPOSE 80

RUN yarn install
CMD yarn start
```

It seems to build OK but I do get a few warnings:

```
Step 9/10 : RUN yarn install
 ---> Running in 6b1b227afaa9
yarn install v1.9.4
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "antd > rc-editor-mention@1.1.6" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@^3.7.4".
warning " > react-apollo@2.1.6" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-client@^2.2.3".
warning " > eslint-config-prettier@2.9.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=3.14.1".
warning "react-app-rewire-less > less-loader@4.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 80.50s.
```

But, when I execute a docker run command I get this error:

```
yarn run v1.9.4
$ NODE_PATH=src:src/components:src/containers:src/helpers react-app-rewired start
/bin/sh: react-app-rewired: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

Comment: You need to copy your code inside the container with COPY or ADD, or git clone inside the container but that's probably more complex unless it is a public repository, otherwise you'll need to provide credentials and you don't want to build an image with credentials inside.

Comment: @MrE Thank you.  You are correct.  It looks like if I cloned it inside of the container, the dependencies are still screwed up.  Seems to be an issue with how yarn is adding peer dependencies.  I don't understand this system well enough to properly troubleshoot -- although I was able to get this to run by manually adding "yarn add xxx" commands.  I can't believe that is the right way, but it does work.

Comment: you're copying everything from your local folder to the docker container. I think this is a bad idea, because it's copying the local node_modules folder and the rest. That may be confusing yarn. I'd just copy the source, and the package.json file. Actually, the package.json first, then run yarn, then copy the sources, so your container build step does not need to rebuild the dependencies installation if they have not changed.